# Issue with using kmeans on filtered pandas data

Tags: python, pandas, k-means

I have imported a CSV file, and filtered two columns. Very standard and working as expected. However, as soon as i run a KMeans test the outcome is unexpected. I am either running it on the entire dataset (not the filtered data) or on the wrong data.

```
# Load data
data = pd.read_csv('ISD.csv', encoding='ISO-8859-1')

# Remove '%' from the entire DataFrame
data = data.apply(lambda x: x.str.rstrip('%') if x.dtype == 'O' else x)

# Replace '#DIV/0!' with NaN
data.replace('#DIV/0!', pd.NA, inplace=True)

# Convert relevant columns to float, replacing missing values with 0
data['Debt to Equity'] = data['Debt to Equity'].replace(pd.NA, '0').astype(float)
```

This loads the data loaded.

```
# Select relevant financial metrics
selected_metrics = data[['Debt to Equity', 'Stable Financial Postion']]

# Apply filters
filtered_data = selected_metrics[(selected_metrics['Stable Financial Postion'] == 1)].copy()

# Check counts of Stable Financial Position in the filtered data
print("Counts of Stable Financial Position in Filtered Data:")
print(filtered_data['Stable Financial Postion'].value_counts())

# Reset index of filtered_data
filtered_data.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
print(filtered_data['Stable Financial Postion'].value_counts())

print (filtered_data['Debt to Equity'].max())
print (filtered_data['Debt to Equity'].min())
```

The result from this is as expected and correct

Counts of Stable Financial Position in Filtered Data:

```
Stable Financial Postion
1    1316
Name: count, dtype: int64
Stable Financial Postion
1    1316
Name: count, dtype: int64
1.923278013
1.25e-09
```

However, in the next step, it seems to break down and the results become unexpected.

```
# Clustering
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3, n_init=10)  # Adjust the number of clusters as needed

# Fit and predict on the filtered data
cluster_labels = kmeans.fit_predict(filtered_data[['Debt to Equity', 'Stable Financial Postion']])

# Assign cluster labels to the original DataFrame
data.loc[filtered_data.index, 'Cluster'] = cluster_labels
```

running the below descriptions gives a max value of 226149 for cluster 0, 370 for cluster 1 and 5000 for cluster 2.

```
# Inspect cluster labels
print("\nCluster Counts:")
print(data['Cluster'].value_counts())

# Explore cluster characteristics
cluster_stats = data.groupby('Cluster')['Debt to Equity'].describe()
print("\nCluster Characteristics:")
print(cluster_stats)
```

the results are below

```
Cluster Counts:
Cluster
0.0    998
1.0    244
2.0     74
Name: count, dtype: int64

Cluster Characteristics:
         count        mean          std  ...       50%       75%            max
Cluster                                  ...                                   
0.0      968.0  524.708244  8306.283145  ...  0.056144  1.629182  226149.000000
1.0      239.0  550.843018  4978.241124  ...  0.054620  1.931508   50000.000000
2.0       71.0   13.488451    64.011376  ...  0.007957  0.373877     370.186275
```

Am I going wrong with the filtering or with the Kmeans test?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. I attached the clusters to the original data and not to the filtered data.